# Reset apache connection number from client

Tags: c#, apache, apache2

i have a c# application for get data from a Page, for do it i need to be logued in.
In The connection numbrer 33 and nexts i get an error.
I can ser this in The headers:

Keep-Alive:

timeout=5, max=32

Is there any way to force apache reset muy connection number from The client?